# Woocommerce My Account Endpoint - how to get ID parameter from URL?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, endpoints

I'm using WooCommerce v3.2.6 and WordPress 4.9.1.
I've added an endpoint to the WooCommerce myaccount area (`view-subscription`):

```
function my_custom_endpoints() {
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'view-subscription', EP_ROOT | EP_PAGES );
}

add_action( 'init', 'my_custom_endpoints' );

function my_custom_query_vars( $vars ) {
    $vars[] = 'view-subscription';
    return $vars;
}

add_filter( 'query_vars', 'my_custom_query_vars', 0 );

function view_subscription_endpoint_content() {
    include get_template_directory().'/woocommerce/myaccount/view-subscription.php'; 
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_account_view-subscription_endpoint', 'view_subscription_endpoint_content' );
```

The endpoint is working but I want to be able to pass the ID of a subscription (a post type) to the endpoint (similar to how view-order works). How can I do this?

eg.

```
myaccount/view-order/21313 - Displays details of order #21313
myaccount/view-subscription/35464 - I want this to display the details of the subscription post #35464.
```

If I go to the above URL `myaccount/view-subscription/35464` , the view-subscription.php template is still loading, but what is the best way to access the ID, 35464, from the URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope it's not too late, but anyway, I know it will help someone else.

`echo get_query_var('your-endpoint');`

So, for your code, it will be:

`echo get_query_var('view-subscription');`

Answer (score 1):

Please use this, it will help me according same as view-order link.

[`wc_get_endpoint_url()`](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wc_get_endpoint_url)

eg.

`myaccount/view-order/21313` - Displays details of order `#21313`
`myaccount/view-coupon/123` - Display details of coupon `#123`